# Why are we initialising valid_input to false and using 'while not' valid_input in this python code

Tags: python-3.x, validation, input, while-loop, boolean-logic

```
def get_yes_or_no(message):
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        answer = input(message)
        answer = answer.upper() # convert to upper case
        if answer == 'Y' or answer == 'N':
            valid_input = True
        else:
            print('Please enter Y for yes or N for no.')
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to even use a `valid_input` variable; you can just have an infinite loop you `return` out of:

```
def get_yes_or_no(message):
    while True:
        answer = input(message).upper() # convert to upper case
        if answer == 'Y' or answer == 'N':
            return answer
        print('Please enter Y for yes or N for no.')
```